# Applying jQuery to control div's css height Novice jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

[Example here](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/test/)

Right now I have a jQuery function for each navigation link to alter the height of each corresponding div to a specific px value, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".class1").click(function() {
        $("#classpanes").css("height","300px");
    });

    $(".class2").click(function() {
        $("#classpanes").css("height","550px");
    });

    $(".class3").click(function() {
        $("#classpanes").css("height","200px");
    });
</script>
```

(this changes the initial height of 300px set in the CSS)

I know this is an awful solution. Additionally it looks pretty rough, mainly because I used jQuery Tools Tabs plugin to fade the divs as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#class ul").tabs("#classpanes > div", {effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: 200});
});
</script>
```

So I was wanting to apply jQuery animation's slide function (?) to slide the div to the correct height when each one is loaded. It would be nice to somehow detect the height of the div, rather than entering it manually.

The one remaining issue is the side navigation links work to resize, but a link within one of the divs isn't picked up by the function (as you can tell in the example).

If there is an issue getting the fading *and* sliding, I'm totally willing to ditch the fade.

Thanks in advance to anyone who has any input!

**Relevant HTML**

```
<div id="class">
    <div id="classnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#1" class="class1">Introductory Classes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2" class="class2">Private Lessons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3" class="class3">Duet Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
    <div id="classpanes">
        <div><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
        <div><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
#class{
    position: relative;
}

#classnav {
    width: 175px;
    float: left;
}

#classpanes {
    position: relative;
    width: 720px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -4px;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 300px;
}

#classpanes div {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spent about one hour on this and finally, it was just one css property creating all the problems. Here is what you need to do;

Replace all your Jquery with:

```
$(function() {
        $("#class ul").tabs("#classpanes > div", {effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: 200});
        $("#classpanes").css("height","auto");
    });
```

And in the CSS remove for `#classpanes div` remove the `position:absolute;` and you are all set.

Here is  a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/mdM8N/3/)

Comment: Thanks so much for your time! Yes, the jQuery Tools Tabs plugin required the absolute position, but obviously it does make more sense to use jQuery alone in this case. So is there any way to add the animation/slide to `$("#classpanes").css("height","auto");`? That's what I was really after.

Comment: The other issue I'm noticing is the shuttering/flashing where it looks like the div that's being called is stacking on top of the current one before it fades out. Like I said in my OP, I'm totally willing to ditch the fade to make the transition smoother and hopefully animated. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you look at the jQuery animate function to get the slide and fade working simulataneously. The best way to do this using jquery tools is to define your own effect using `$.tools.tabs.addEffect`. I also changed the classpanes css to `height: auto`. I have a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6daP/13/